# multiple dispatch in redux action

Tags: redux, react-redux

I wanted to dispatch an action from another action but not able to do so.  When I try to do so it not able to found `getAllUser` method.
Below is my action class.

```
    export const myActions = {

        getAllUser() {
            return (dispatch) => {
                makeApiCall()
                    .then((response) => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: USER_SUCCESS,
                            payload: response,
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: USER_FAILURE,
                            payload: error,
                        });
                    });
            };
        },

        addUser(user) {
            return (dispatch) => {
                makeApiCall(user)
                    .then((response) => {
                        /*
                        Need help here : 
                        wants to call above getAllUser()
                           .then(() => 
                              dispatch({
                                 type: ADD_SUCCESS,
                                 payload: response,
                              });
                            )
                        */
            };
        },
    };
```

I have tried various approaches like,

```
myActions.getAllUser()
    .then((response) => 
       dispatch({
           type: ADD_SUCCESS,
           payload: response,
       });
    );
```

and trying do dispatch directly,

```
        const self = this;
        dispatch(self.getAllUser());
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_SUCCESS,
            payload: response,
        });
```

One more way around this is after `addUser` success, update the reducer and than from UI call `getAccount` again to refresh the results, but just curious to know on how can I achieve this using multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the functions individually instead of wrapping it under the same object:

```
export const getAllUser = () => dispatch => { ... }

export const addUser = () => dispatch => { 
  ... 
  dispatch(getAllUser());
}
```

You can still import them all if desired:

```
import * as myActions from '...';
```

Or you can declare `getAllUser` first then add to `myActions`, but the above solution is much cleaner.

```
const getAllUser = ...
const myActions = {
  getAllUser,
  addUser = ... { dispatch(getAllUser()) }
}
```